# Trouble finding element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to coding and I am trying to make a form filler on Nike.com using the Selenium Chrome webdriver. However, a pop-up comes up about cookied and I am finding it hard to remove it so I can fill out the form.
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeQ3w.png)
and my code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#Initialise a chrome browser and return it
def initialisebrowser():
    browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'''C:\Users\ben_s\Downloads\chromedriver''')
    return browser

#Pass in the browser and url, and go to the url with the browser
def geturl(browser, url):
    browser.get(url)

#Initialise the browser (and store the returned browser)
browser = initialisebrowser()

#Go to a url(nike.com) with the browser
geturl(browser,"https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/s/register")
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("nsg-button.nsg-grad--nike-orange.yes-button.cookie-settings-button.js-yes-button")
button.click()
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ben_s\Desktop\Nike Account Generator.py", line 19, in <module>
    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("nsg-button.nsg-grad--nike-orange.yes-button.cookie-settings-button.js-yes-button")
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 557, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"nsg-button.nsg-grad--nike-orange.yes-button.cookie-settings-button.js-yes-button"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Any ideas, pointers or solutions to the problem are much apprieciated

Comment: class name is right ?

Comment: I prevously copied the class name from the element and that gave the same error. The attempt you see is me putting dots instead of spaces for the class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name` recives one class as parameter

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('yes-button')
```

The parameter you provided is combination of all the webelement classes, and is used by `css_selector`

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.nsg-button.nsg-grad--nike-orange.yes-button.cookie-settings-button.js-yes-button')
```

Note that you need to add `.` before the first class as well, otherwise it is treated as tag name. For example in this case

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.nsg-button.nsg-grad--nike-orange.yes-button.cookie-settings-button.js-yes-button')
```

To make sure the button exists before clicking on it you can use [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'yes-button')))
button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped so much, especially the explicit wait

Answer (score 0):

use `time.sleep` to wait until the popup will load, and after that you can use `cookie-settings-button-container` class that is parrent of the `btn` this will work.

```
time.sleep(1)                                                                                                                                                                   
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("cookie-settings-button-container")
button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It's a lot clearer now. Out of interest, will I be able to find any element using the parent class in the future?

Comment: don't do this... using a static sleep to wait for anything is a horrible idea.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg i'm agree with you, i forgot about `WebDriverWait` that was in @Guy answer